# Chinese Remainder Theorem for Remainder Intervals

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, congruences

Given $n$ natural numbers $m_1,\dots,m_n$ and $n$ remainder intervals $[a_1,b_1],\dots,[a_n,b_n]$ holding $a_i < b_i$ for all $i\leq n$ the task is to search for the **smallest** natural number $x$ that holds
$$(\exists y_i\in[a_i,b_i]:x\equiv y_i\mod m_i) \quad \forall i \leq n$$
I don't want anyone to solve this for me. But maybe I'm missing some paper?

Comment: You might consider the tag "reference-request" if you want to emphasize that you're more interested in pointers to the relevant literature than you are to mathematical commentary.

Comment: I suspect this is NP-hard if not NP-complete.  I would also be interested in references to this problem.  I am reminded of a continued fraction type algorithm for the postage stamp problem for n=2 or n=3; perhaps you can reduce the postage stamp problem to this.  Gerhard "But Don't Try Mailing It" Paseman, 2019.08.14.

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/94227/fuzzy-chinese-remainder-theorem-np-hard which shows NP-hardness in the case of arbitrary $m_i$. It's possible that nothing is actually known in the case of (relatively) prime $m_i$.

Answer (score 1):

First off, we may assume that $m_i$ are powers of distinct primes (otherwise we can split them into powers of primes and merge powers of the same prime).

There is an approach based on the [Coppersmith method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith_method) that may work in some cases, depending on the length of intervals and how small is the smallest solution as compared to $M:=m_1m_2\cdots m_n$. In fact, it's applicable for any given sets of residues modulo each $m_i$, not necessarily intervals. In your case these sets are $A_i := \{ k\in\mathbb{Z}\mid a_i\leq k\leq b_i\}$. For further details, see my [other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/224033) (where $p_i:=m_i$).