# Chinese remainder theorem for target interval

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, congruences

Given $n$ pairwise coprime natural numbers $m_{1}, \dots, m_{n}$ with remainders $y_{i}$, for all $i \leq n$. Furthermore, we have a target interval $I := \left[ a, b \right]$, with $1 \leq a < b \leq M$, $M := \prod_{i = 1}^{n} m_{i}$.

The task is, to find all tuples $T := \left(y_{1}, \dots, y_{n}\right)$ such that

$$
\exists \ x \in I, \forall i \in [1:n], x \equiv y_{i} \mod m_{i}. 
$$

1. Does exist a way to find all $T$'s apart from trivial cases like $I = [1, M]$ or brute forcing?
2. Or as even harder task: Does exist a way to find all $T$'s if you limit the set of allowed remainders? (Like, in our example for $m_{2} = 5$, for example only allow the remainders $y_{2}$ to be $\{ 1, 3 \}$.)

**Edit:**
Since the problem seems to be not clear for everybody, I want to give an example.

Be $m_{1} = 3$, and $m_{2} = 5$, so we have possible remainders $y_{1} \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$, and $y_{2} \in \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$.

It follows the two equations

$$
x = 3k_{1} + y_{1}\\
x = 5k_{2} + y_{2},
$$

with $k_{1}, k_{2} \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$. Assuming now, we only want $x$ in the interval $I := \left[ 8, 10\right]$.

This $x \in I$ can be written as

$$
x = 8 = 3\cdot 2 + 2 = 5\cdot 1 + 3\\
x = 9 = 3\cdot 3 + 0 = 5\cdot 1 + 4\\
x = 10 = 3\cdot 3 + 1 = 5\cdot 2 + 0
$$

So, we get the tuples $T_{1} = \left(2, 3\right)$, $T_{2} = \left(0, 4\right)$ and $T_{3} = \left(1, 0\right)$.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to determine the image of $I$ by the map $x \mapsto (x \mod m_1,\ldots,x \mod m_n)$?

Comment: I need $T_{j}$, so that $x \in I$.

Comment: I do not understand. And what is $j$? Do you want to characterize the $n$-uples $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ such that the system of congruences $\forall i \le n, x \equiv y_i \mod m_i$ has some solution in $I$?

Comment: $j$ is just a label for all tuples which solves this problem.

Comment: With your first sentence of "Given $n$ natural numbers $m_{1}, \dots, m_{n}$ with remainders $y_{i}$, for all $i \leq n$", the "remainders $y_{i}$" are after division by what value(s)?

Comment: The remainder $y_{i}$ after division with $m_{i}$. You have $x = m_{i}k + y_{i}$, $k_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$. So, you start with the general set of all possible remainders $y_{i} \in \{ 0, \dots,  m_{i} - 1 \}$, and asking which specific ones you need to get $x \in I$.

Comment: You can formulate this problem as an ILP

Comment: Yes, I know, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: There must be several typos which need correcting for this to make sense. The double-subscripted $y_{i,j}$ aren't used outside of the first definition of $T_j$; $x$ is unbound (should it be bound by the existential quantifier?); and "find all $T_j$ such that ... there exists $T_j$" only makes sense if there's aliasing and the two references to $T_j$ are to different objects, but in that case neither of them is used anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, will rewrite it. Honestly, I didn't expect that my writing is so confusing. I always labeling possible several solutions with an own index, that is the only reason for the "j". So, assume there exists two possible tuple, you would have simple $T_{1}$, and $T_{2}$, to make clear that you have in fact two solutions. I will rewrite it. Seems to be a good idea ;).

Comment: What does the first sentence mean?  Does it mean that $m_j \equiv y_i \pmod{i}$ for all i,j?

Comment: Which first sentence? You have $x = m_{i}k_{i} + y_{i}$, $k_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$. You have all $m_{i}$ given and an interval $I$. Now you are searching for $y_{i}$ so, that the resulting $x$ is in $I$.

Comment: I have just tried to transcript the condition. I hope I did not misunderstood: the previous formulation `find all T such that there exists (x,T)...' was not understandable.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457174/chinese-remainder-theorem-for-target-interval#comment1184222_457174), thank you for attempting to make things clearer; but, for ambiguous questions, it is usually better, for the asker and for the community, to let the asker take the time to communicate themselves clearly, rather than for the community to edit towards a guess (inevitably with some chance of misunderstanding, because of the ambiguous phrasing) of what was meant.

Comment: To be honest, for me the rewritten one reads exactly the same like my version before. I would interpret it the same. Never expected that such simple line could great so much confusion. :P

Comment: The meaningless $\exists T$ (since you look for a condition on $T$) has been suppressed, the order of the quantificators has been clarified : $\exists x... \forall i$. Parentehis $(x \in I)$ at the end were very ambiguous, it could mean $\forall x$, $\forall i... \exists x$ or $\exists x... \forall i$. And it should now be suppressed since $\exists x... \forall i$ is written at the beginning.

Comment: Do you assume that $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ are coprime? If yes, it is worth writing it. In this case, the solutions of the system $\forall i \in [1:n], x \equiv y_{i} \mod m_{i}$ can be given explicitly, using a Bezout relation involving the products $P_i = (m_1 \cdots m_n)/m_i$.

Comment: Yes, coprime. But Bezout doesn't work if you limit the remainders (question 2). I couldn't find a possibility for this with Bezout. With Bezout you allways get all possible solutions, and it's unclear for me, how to get it limited (I'm talking about question 2 ;).

Comment: The problem is. let's assume I limit the remainders $y_{1}$, then Bezout gives me all solutions for $y_{2}$ which also include the remainders which I don't want (and vise versa). Couldn't find an approach for this apart from saying "this set is the solution apart from values.....".

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the number of tuples you want to find is the size of the interval, so you can't do better than finding the representation of the first number and then repeatedly incrementing it.

For the second question, generally it seems quite hard (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224013/minimal-solution-of-simultaneous-congruences), [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338350/chinese-remainder-theorem-for-remainder-intervals) and [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/94227/fuzzy-chinese-remainder-theorem-np-hard)). If the sets are continuous ranges (or composed from a small number of them), and $n$ is small you can formulate this as an ILP with a small number of variables and try to solve it.